# Why the macroscopic approach towards studying matter in classical thermodynamics only applicable when number of constituents are large?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In classical thermodynamics, we study matter macroscopically. That is we are not interested in the individual behavior of its constituents but rather in their bulk behavior. We describe matter using macroscopic quantities like pressure, temperature, volume, mass, etc.

I read in a book, we can apply this macroscopic approach only when the matter contains a large number of constituents. If the number of constituents is small we need to go with statistical thermodynamics.

It wasn't stated explicitly as to why we can use the macroscopic approach with only a large number of constituents but not with a small number. What exactly goes wrong with a small number of particles that we have to resort to statistical thermodynamics?

Comment: What you are asking is basically known as the "thermodynamic limit": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit

Comment: @Yejus Thermodynamic limit means that one is approaching Thermodynamics from Statistical Mechanics. However, this question looks at the problem from the other side (Classical Thermodynamics).

Answer (score 4):

From the formulation of the question, I assume that the answer should take the point of view of Classical Thermodynamics without mixing it with Statistical Mechanics.

Classical Thermodynamics hinges on a certain number of hypotheses on the systems it can be applied.

One of them is the extensiveness of the energy, which requires that the energy of a system made by putting together two equal subsystems is exactly twice the energy of each subsystem.

Such a property cannot be taken for granted automatically. In particular, if the subsystems are too small, the sum of the energies of the separated subsystems is not the same as the energy of the compound system: the difference being a *surface* term whose weight with respect to the bulk contributions vanishes as $V^{-\frac13}$ for large volumes $V$.

A second independent hypothesis is that all thermodynamic quantities have well-definite and constant values at thermodynamic equilibrium. It turns out that if a system is too small, thermodynamic quantities may fluctuate around their equilibrium value. Large systems ensure vanishing relative fluctuations. If the system is so small that fluctuations are not negligible, the probability of such fluctuations becomes a central quantity for theory, and we need Statistical Thermodynamics.

Comment: Regarding the wall effect, that's true, but what about an ideal gas with no interactions? This leaves us with fluctuations as the answer, but where do fluctuations come from? My point being that we cannot avoid statistical arguments if we want to give a qualitative but still somewhat convincing answer.

Comment: @Themis The ideal gas is a  special system, so it is not general enough. I agree that a convincing and general treatment of fluctuations involves Statistical Mechanics. But Equilibrium Thermodynamics has a validity independent of Statistical Mechanics. Classical thermodynamic equilibrium systems do not show measurable fluctuations. Then, that becomes the proper domain of Thermodynamics.

Comment: @Themis But even for an ideal gas, the entropy is not extensive before taking the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Using the correct Boltzmann formula for entropy  the ideal gas entropy is an extensive quantity (see https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equazione_di_Sackur-Tetrode ).

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Yes, but thermodynamics works only in the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: But the Sackur-Tetrode equation only holds in the thermodynamic limit, no? Cf. *What good is the thermodynamic limit?. D.F. Styer.*

Comment: @Themis Indeed, that's my point: Even for a non-interacting system you need to consider large systems in order for thermodynamics to apply. I may have misunderstood your first comment, tho. And if so, just ignore my comment(s). You're right that (obviously) interactions do not play a role for the ideal gas; but still you need a large system to apply concepts of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 3):

The question is so fundamental that cannot be answered in a simple way. But here is a take.

Thermodynamics is intimately connected to probabilities. To know anything about a stochastic process, say the flipping of a coin, we need a lot of observations (or a lot of coins thrown simultaneously). If we toss a die only twice we cannot tell if it is fair or not. But if we toss it 1000 times we can answer this question with more confidence.

In thermodynamics we are interested in predicting various average properties, for example, the mean energy of a system that is in thermal contact with its surroundings, or the mean mean number of molecular collisions with the walls of the container and so on. These statistical averages require a large number of particles.